# Spark Structured Streaming won't pull the final batch from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I noticed that SSS won't process a waiting batch if there are no batches after that. What I saw is that Spark must always leave one batch on Kafka waiting to be consumed when it is writing Parquet to HDFS.

This is to do with the way Spark cleans up after each batch, apparently.

There is a JIRA for it at:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24156

that says it's resolved in 2.4.0 but my code is using 2.4.2 yet I still see Spark reluctant to consume another batch from Kafka if it means there is nothing else waiting to be processed in the topic.

Do I have to do something special to exploit the behaviour that SPARK-24156 says it has introduced?

Comment: Highly unlikely, what would be the benefit of that?

Comment: Looks like not succesfully resolved

Answer (score 0):

Given the recent activity with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24156?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17405606#comment-17405606 using Spark 3.x, we can conclude I think the issue was never really resolved and remains with us.